# How do you know a Gift Card was used with a Shopify Order

Tags: shopify, orders

If a customer uses a gift card to pay for all or part of an order, how do we know that amount from the order details? Is there a way to sum up the total amount of a gift card used on an order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can receive this information with Transactions API. Each order on Shopify might have multiple transactions. In transaction object, you can find information about Gift Card ID and the amount

**For example**

Response from `GET /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.json` method when order **paid** with Gift Card and COD:

```
{
    "transactions": [{
        "id": 89999999999,
        "order_id": 9999999999,
        "amount": "25.00",
        "kind": "sale",
        "gateway": "gift_card",
        "status": "success",
        "message": null,
        "created_at": "2017-09-28T16:34:41+04:00",
        "test": false,
        "authorization": null,
        "currency": "AED",
        "location_id": null,
        "user_id": null,
        "parent_id": null,
        "device_id": null,
        "receipt": {
            "gift_card_id": 999999,
            "gift_card_last_characters": "98h8"
        },
        "error_code": null,
        "source_name": "web"
    }, {
        "id": 89999999999,
        "order_id": 9999999999,
        "amount": "875.00",
        "kind": "sale",
        "gateway": "Cash on Delivery (COD)",
        "status": "pending",
        "message": "Pending the Cash on Delivery (COD) payment from the buyer",
        "created_at": "2017-09-28T16:34:41+04:00",
        "test": false,
        "authorization": null,
        "currency": "AED",
        "location_id": null,
        "user_id": null,
        "parent_id": null,
        "device_id": null,
        "receipt": {},
        "error_code": null,
        "source_name": "web"
    }, {
        "id": 89999999999,
        "order_id": 9999999999,
        "amount": "875.00",
        "kind": "sale",
        "gateway": "Cash on Delivery (COD)",
        "status": "success",
        "message": "Marked the Cash on Delivery (COD) payment as received",
        "created_at": "2017-10-02T19:13:35+04:00",
        "test": false,
        "authorization": null,
        "currency": "AED",
        "location_id": null,
        "user_id": null,
        "parent_id": 777777777,
        "device_id": null,
        "receipt": {},
        "error_code": null,
        "source_name": "web"
    }]
}
```